# How to add a layout in a template in Joomla?

Tags: layout, joomla

I'd like to add an additional layout to one of the core components.

Is there a way to do this in a template without adding any files to the Joomla core installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This possibility appeared in the Joomla `1.6`: [Introduction to Alternative Layout Feature in Version 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_1.6#Introduction_to_Alternative_Layout_Feature_in_Version_1.6)

Answer (score 0):

In the template directory you can add a file called components/$name.html.php, where $name is the name of the component without the com_ prefix. Then it should pick up this file instead of the one supplied with core joomla.

Comment: That's the view AFAIK, not the layout.

Comment: What do you mean by layout of the component then? CSS?

Comment: Layouts are means to display a view. They are mentioned here: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Layouts

Comment: @georg: Ah my misunderstanding, sorry. Then I have no idea, but I guess it should be possible to deduce if this works from the code that loads the layout of the components.